# Regression Analysis with Events

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, recurrent-events

how can I use the event's to predict number of visitors per month, I have history of three years of Data.

the layout of the data like this :
Month_Year  , Number of Visitors (target variable), count of Trip Advisor Visitors  Currency Exchange USD,  Event Name

I want to build a regression model using the above variables, but I don't know how to use the event variable.

Any idea's about that?

Comment: The Event Name variable can be made categorical.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you mean convert every value in the event name column into categorical variable with 1/0 values?

Comment: Depends on how many events you have. Although most software will automatically implement the factor transform of your data.

Comment: I have 400 unique events, so this mean, I am going to create a matrix of ( 36*400 ), 36 " three years of history " 
400 "column for each event value" .  
For each target value " number of visitors", I will have multiple events columns with value equal to one, " because multiple events can happened within same month"